# My BufferedImage is just 1 px tall, even when i give it a value in initialization

Tags: java, io, bufferedimage, dimension

i was doing a program for pixel art, and there is a grid of jpanels that get paainted as the user clicks. the grid is represented by a multidimensional array. the problem is that i'm trying to save all as a png image file, but for some reason it just saves the first line of the grid ( or the multiDimensionalArray[0][i]). Here is the code for the save method:

```
public void save(JPanel p, Pixel[][] array, int temp ){
    try{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(temp,temp, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
    for(int y = 0; y < temp; y++){
        for(int j = 0; j < temp; j++){
            Color c = array[y][j].getStateColor();
            g.setColor(c);
            g.fillRect(x,y, 1, 1);
            x++;
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("pixel.png"));
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error saving the image");;e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

You see that i instantiated a bufferedimage and specified the width and height, but it just saves one line of pixels. How do i fix that?

Comment: You're iterating over `y` and `j`, but filling the pixels with `x` and `y`. I can't imagine that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a logic error, also I don't see x initialised where is it in your code?
You might want to swap the

```
g.fillRect(x,y, 1, 1);
```

for

```
g.fillRect(y,j, 1, 1);
```

Should look something like this

```
public void save(JPanel p, Pixel[][] array, int temp ){
    try{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(temp,temp, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
    for(int y = 0; y < temp; y++){
        for(int j = 0; j < temp; j++){
            Color c = array[y][j].getStateColor();
            g.setColor(c);
            g.fillRect(y,x, 1, 1);
            x++;
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("pixel.png"));
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error saving the image");;e.printStackTrace();}
}
```